# Cast Sender App Shows Pause Button Instead of Stop Button

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

So I am trying to build a sender app for chromecast that will stream Live feeds only. The trouble is the various framework dialogs all show a Pause button, when in fact I need a Stop button (or for the feed to at least jump back to current live time when it is resumed)

The only information I can find on this through the documentation is some vague snippet

> When your sender app is playing a video or audio live stream, the SDK automatically displays a play/stop button in place of the play/pause button in the mini controller.

When I create the GCKMediaInformation object to load on the chromecast, I set its Media Stream Type to Live with a content type of "vnd.apple.mpegURL" But this has no effect.

Does anybody have any idea how I can make the stop button appear instead of the pause button?

EDIT:

A strip down version of the logic used to load live stream feed

```
let metaData = GCKMediaMetadata(metadataType: .generic)
metaData.setString(selectedChannel!.channelName, forKey: kGCKMetadataKeyTitle)        
metaData.addImage(GCKImage(url: URL(string: selectedChannel!.imgURL)!, width: 10, height: 20))

mediaInfo = GCKMediaInformation(contentID: selectedChannel!.vidURL, streamType: GCKMediaStreamType.live, contentType: "vnd.apple.mpegURL", metadata: metaData, streamDuration: 0, mediaTracks: nil, textTrackStyle: nil, customData: nil)

if sessionManager.currentCastSession != nil {
    switchToCastingMode()
}


func switchToCastingMode() {
    print("switching to CAST mode")
    if let session = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession {
        if session.remoteMediaClient?.mediaStatus?.mediaInformation?.contentID != mediaInfo?.contentID {
            session.remoteMediaClient?.loadMedia(mediaInfo!, autoplay: true)
            GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().presentDefaultExpandedMediaControls()
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing the media stream type to other values, but this has no effect either :(

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug on the SDK side. Please open a ticket on our issue tracker so we can properly investigate, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to play HLS through chromecast its just getting started to play then automatically gettinga paused, Any idea or help?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Currently going down the same rabbit hole.

Comment: I did not, our app still shows the pause button instead of the stop button (it also somehow fell off our issue tracker - our iOS dev will be pleased). If you do manage to solve this, please do share